# build check box in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

views.py

```
def what(request):
      user = request.user
      report = Report.objects.get(user=user.id)
      reportnotesform=ReportNotes(instance=report)
      reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)
      typeList = Types.objects.filter(user=user, is_active=True,parent_type_id=None)
      list = []
      for type in typeList:
            if not type.parent_type_id:
                 list.append(type)
                 subtype = Types.objects.filter(parent_type_id=type.id, is_active=True)
                 for subtypes in subtype:
                      list.append(subtypes)
      if request.method == 'POST':
            ReportType.objects.filter(report=report).delete()
            checked_ones = [unicode(x) for x in subtype if unicode(x) in request.POST.keys()]
            reportnotesform=ReportNotes(request.POST,instance=report)
            if reportnotesform.is_valid():
                 report=reportnotesform.save(commit=False)     
                 report.user=request.user
                 report.save()
                 for entry in checked_ones:
                      r = ReportType()
                      r.report = report 
                      r.title = entry
                      r.save()
            return redirect('/member/where/')
      checked_ones = [x.title for x in ReportType.objects.filter(report=report)]  
      return render(request, 'incident/what.html',
      {
      'newreport_menu': True,
      'typeList':list,

      'checked_ones':checked_ones,
    #  'typelist': typelist,
      'ReportNotes':reportnotesform,
      'ReportForm':reportform
      })
```

models.py

```
class ReportType(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    title = models.CharField('Incident Type', max_length=200)
```

template

```
 {% for type in typeList%}
  {% if type.parent_type_id == None %}
  <h1>{{type.title}}</h1>
 {% else %}
 <p><input type="checkbox">{{type.title}}</input></p>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am using model form to display the check box,dynamically.

This is my view where i am taking the values from database and displaying.The values filtered by typelist object requires to display values along with check box.For types object,doesn't matter.Is any way to do it in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<h1> {% for type in types %}{{type.title}}<br />{% endfor %}</h1>          
<form action="" method="post">
{% for field in typelist %}
{% if field.title in checked_ones %}
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="{{field}}">{{ field }}</label><br /> 
{% else %}
<label><input type="checkbox" name="{{field}}">{{ field }}</label><br /> 
{%endif%}
{% endfor %} 
</form>


def what(request):
    user = request.user

    types = Types.objects.filter(user=user.id, parent_type_id=None).order_by('title')
    typelist=Types.objects.filter(user=user.id,parent_type_id__isnull=False).order_by('title')
    reporttypeForm = ReportTypeForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ReportType.objects.filter(report=#your report).delete()
        checked_ones = [unicode(x) for x in typelists if unicode(x) in request.POST.keys()]
        for entry in checked_ones:
            r = ReportType()
            r.report = # the hardcoded report
            r.title = entry
            r.save()
        ...
        reporttypeForm = ReportTypeForm(request.POST)        
        if reporttypeForm.is_valid():
            reporttypeForm.save()
    checked_ones = [x.title for x in ReportType.objects.filter(report=#your report)]
    return render(request, 'incident/what.html',
        {
            'checked_ones':checked_ones,
            'newreport_menu': True,
            'types':types,
            'typelist': typelist,
            'reporttypeForm':ReportTypeForm
    })
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about why you're trying to do it this way, it looks like you're overcomplicating your problem by trying to make it dynamic, when you could just use a `models.BooleanField()`, which Django will automatically display as a checkbox. It'd be simpler, and make the code easier to read too.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to add a field to your model for that value, and define the field as a `models.BooleanField(blank=True,null=True)`. This way you can leave it empty 'til later when you use it.